# pandas equivalent of select sum(t.col1 * t.col2) / sum(t.col3) from table as t group by t.col4

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find pandas equivalent of sql...

```
select sum(t.col1 * t.col2) / sum(t.col3) from table as t group by t.col4
```

I did

```
df.groupby(['col4'])[['col3']].sum()
```

but it only produce the sum(t.3)...

is there a one-line statement to achieve this kind of task in pandas?

Comment: kindly provide data, with expected output. It looks like something that can be achieved with ``transform``, but data makes it more concrete and easier to decipher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df['n'] = df['col1'].mul(df['col2'])
gr = df.groupby(['col4'])
res = gr['n'].sum().div(gr['col3'].sum())
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['col4'])
col1 = df_grouped['col1']
col2 = df_grouped['col2']
col3 = df_grouped['col3']
col1col2 = col1.mul(col2).sum()
res = col1col2.div(col3.sum())
```

I'm not sure if it's correct or not but I hope it helps.

Comment: This line will fail: `col1col2 = col1.mul(col2).sum()` - once you fix it, you'll end up with my answer...

Comment: I didn't have the time to try it. Can you explain why it will fail?

Comment: Because `.mul()` + any other arithmetic operation is implemented for `pandas.Series`, eventually `pandas.DataFrame`, whereas when you invoke `.groupby()` you make this grouped object, which in essence is analogical to `dict`, where keys are grouped columns, and values are dataframes associated with individual group - it doesn't have much more to it - it's an interim state in short...